# Why does Tkinter label crash the window python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Python Tkinter label cause window to say not responding when i use it more than once in 5 seconds or so.

Here is my code i am calling it with the variable data which is just a basic string

```
def print_data(data):
    L1 = Tkinter.Label(app, text="You: " + data)
    L1.pack()
```

Comment: Do you have code where you call the `mainloop()`?    Also, each time your function is called, it adds a new label to the existing window, as they accumulate, this may cause a problem.

Comment: Show s a complete program. Are you using both `grid` and `pack` for widgets that have the same oarent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue i was running the script externally to my main script. I was calling the print data script without calling mainloop(). Thanks everyone :)